# Combining audio outputs once amplified

Tags: audio, mobile

I'm familiar of course with the preferable way to mix audio, that is prior to amplification. However, I have a few mobile radios with roughly 1 watt audio outputs, which I would like to send their audio to a single monitor speaker - and simplify things.

I suppose there are 2 ways:

1. Use larger variable pots for each of the inputs. Simple but the pots might be more expensive.
2. Attenuate the audio from the radios - could use a fixed resistor for this on each. Then amplify the combined audio.

I was thinking #1 - passive - would be easier and cheaper, but  #2 may make more sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: Option 2. But I can't think of the text for it right now (damn headache).

Answer (score 1):

I would use option 2.  That way you don't have to variable-attenuate power.  You can use a single pot to blend between the outputs of the two radios.  The output of this will be much higher impedance than a speaker requires, so you feed that into a power amp to drive a speaker.  You may have to attenuate the output of the pot a bit to keep the power amp from being overdriven.