# Combine stereo audio amplifier outputs

Tags: speakers, watts

I got [this](http://www.hifiengine.com/library/technics/su-300.shtml) receiver. Its output power is 2 x 30W on 8 ohms. My question is: is it possible to combine the power from these 2 channels and connect both channels to a single 60W speaker? And if it's possible what will I need. My goal is to connect just 1 bass speaker to the whole receiver, using its whole power.

Comment: Please don't accept an answer unless it really answers your question. You accepted an answer that didn't work for you, and fewer people will see your question because it appears to have been answered, so you are less likely to get another suggestion.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/80926/2028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in some amplifiers and it's called "bridging" or a ["bridge tied load"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge-tied_load) configuration. You need an inverting stage in front of one of the channels to make it inverting. The input signal is then split into the two channels and the output is taken as the potential difference between the two channel outputs. You have to be careful here because since the maximum voltage swing is twice, on paper, it looks like a quadrupling of the power is possible; it would be foolhardy to assume that this can actually be obtained.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. As I checked I think my amplifier doesn't support bridging. Is it possible to make this inverting stage on my apmlifier? I'm new into these things, sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: It's may be possible to do these modifications on this amplifier. To be able to give a definite, "Yes", it is necessary to study the schematics and the board and chassis layout.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any source, where I can read how I can implement this. I googled "invert stage", but since I'm not familiar with such stuffs I have no idea how I can do it.

Comment: I've taken a look at the [service manual for this amp](http://elektrotanya.com/technics_su-300_sm.pdf/download.html) and have some ideas. You have to know what you're doing; the question is too broad for this site.  I would make a small daughter-board with an op-amp on it and a few passive components. I'd find a source of power within the amp to hook it up to, and tap into a circuit board trace to insert the circuit, like perhaps the hijacking one of the inputs like CD/AUX.  That's the general idea; the devil is in the details, of course.

Comment: Seems this is gonna be too hard for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Deepsy An idea is to build an inverter as an external box, which then feeds into one of the receiver's inputs.