# 8 ohm amp to 4 ohm speaker

Tags: amplifier, wiring, speakers, watts

I got amp which produces 2 x 30W output on 8\$\Omega\$. Is it possible for each channel to connect a 60W 4\$\Omega\$ speaker? Is it possible to do such thing and how I can wire it?

Comment: How is this question different from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82295/combine-stereo-audio-amplifier-outputs ?

Comment: In the question you posted I wanna combine the channels. In this question I would like to reduce ohms and increase watts.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlikely that you can extract 60W from an amplifier designed to provide 30W for more than a few milliseconds. If it were that easy you could short the amplifier outputs and extract infinite power.

You can of course use two 4\$\Omega\$ speakers in series to replace an 8\$\Omega\$ speaker, as long as you are careful to connect them in phase.

Comment: just 1 more question. What will be the difference between 1 30W 8ohm bass and 2 x 30W 4ohm bass speakers? Which one would you prefer and why? @JoeHass

Comment: Well, the 4ohm speakers can handle a total of 60W, twice as much as the single 8ohm 30W speaker. If that's important to you then you should choose the 4ohm speakers. There's no way to say any more based on the information given.

Comment: double watts means double loudness?

Comment: @Deepsy 10 times watts means double loudness. A 10W amp/speaker is twice as loud as a 1W amp/speaker. Doubling the power means a 3dB increase in power and a 10dB sounds twice as loud. Doubling the power is about 30% louder.